# xpath difference between starts-with() ends-with() and =

Tags: xpath

Im automaticaly generating the version with starts-with() ends-with() and now I was wandering if i should add an extra case if they have the same text to compare than it should replace it with an =

Is there a difference between `//*[starts-with(., 'hello') and ends-with(., 'hello')]` and `//*[.='hello']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the same, there can be stuff in between. For example `hello hello`.